# Can not copy data from s3 to redshift cluster in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I have set up a redshift cluster in a private subnet. I can successfully connect to my redshift cluster and do basic SQL queries through DBeaver.

I need to upload some file from s3 to redshift as well, so I set up a s3 gateway in my private subnet and updated the route table for my private subnet to add the required route as follow:

```
Destination       Target                 Status            Propagated
192.168.0.0/16    local                  active            No   
pl-7ba54012 (com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3, 52.219.80.0/20, 3.5.128.0/21, 52.219.96.0/20, 52.92.76.0/22)   vpce-04eed78f4db84ae49  
active             No   
0.0.0.0/0         nat-0a73ba7659e887232  active            No
```

However, I can not run the copy query from my s3 bucket

```
copy venue
from 's3://*****/tickit/venue_pipe.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::******:role/global-dev-rdt-role-S3ReadonlyAccess'
region 'us-east-2';
```

There is no restricitve policies on my bucket and public and private subnet security groups and I already can run SQL queries on my redshift cluster in a private subnet.

update:
the security group for redshift cluster allow all conection to port 5439

```
Type         Protocol      Port Range     Source      Description
Redshift     TCP           5439           0.0.0.0/0
Redshift     TCP           5439           ::/0
SSH          TCP           22             sg-0f933e18d6c1967b8
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not run the copy query"? Can you share the error message or describe the problem for us?

Comment: Unless you have activated [Enhanced VPC Routing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-redshift-now-supports-enhanced-vpc-routing/), I don't think you need to use a VPC Endpoint to connect Redshift to S3, since the traffic does not go via the VPC.

Comment: It takes very long time and the query returns with a failed status..I have also enabled VPC routing as this should avoid traffic from going through internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "s3 gateway"? Are you referring to a VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3?

Comment: Yes, I meant the endpoint for s3 in the private subnet in VPC.

Comment: By the way, how do you connect to the Redshift cluster? Is your cluster in a public subnet or a private subnet? If it is in a **public** subnet, then you will need to add the VPC Endpoint to the route table that the public subnet.

Comment: it is in a private subnet and its security group has a rule to allow all connections to port 5439. "Redshift,TCP,5439,0.0.0.0/0". It is somehow strange unless I enable the enhanced routing I can not run copy command.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a new **VPC with a Public Subnet and a Private Subnet** (no NAT Gateway)
- Launched a 1-node **Amazon Redshift cluster** in the private subnet

  - Enhanced VPC Routing = No
  - Publicly accessible = No
- Launched an **Amazon EC2 Linux instance** in the public subnet
- Ran `sudo yum install postgresql` on the EC2 instance
- Established a connection to the Redshift cluster via `psql` on the EC2 instance (`psql -h xx.yy.ap-southeast-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U username`)
- Created a table (`create table foo(id integer);`)
- Loaded the table (`copy foo from 's3://my-bucket/bar.txt' iam_role 'xxx';`)

This **worked successfully**, with a message of:

```
INFO:  Load into table 'foo' completed, 4 record(s) loaded successfully.
```

Therefore, **a VPC Endpoint/NAT Gateway is not required to perform a `COPY` command from Redshift**. The Redshift cluster has its own special way to connect to S3, seemingly via a Redshift 'backend'.

If the data is being loaded from Amazon S3 in the same Region, then the traffic would stay wholly within the AWS network. If the data was coming from a different region, it would still be encrypted because communication with Amazon S3 would be via HTTPS.

**Second test: Using Enhanced VPC Networking**

To mirror your situation, I launched a different Redshift cluster with **Enhanced VPC routing enabled**.

When I ran the `COPY` command, it predictably hung because I did not configure a means for the Redshift cluster to access Amazon S3 via the VPC.

I then created a **VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3** and connected it to the private subnet with a "Full Access" policy.

Then, when I re-ran the `COPY` command, it successfully loaded data from Amazon S3.

**Bottom line:** It worked for me. You might want to compare your configuration with the above steps that I took.

Comment: For the second scenrio, did you set up the redshift cluster in a private subnet with a NAT gateway? I can run the copy command when I disable enhanced routing but not when I enable it.

Comment: Both scenarios used the same VPC: Public Subnet with Internet Gateway and EC2 instance, Private Subnet with Redshift cluster. Neither scenario used a NAT Gateway. Second scenario also had a VPC Endpoint for S3 connected to the private subnet.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my mistake, I had to put a NAT gateway in the public subnet and also attach an internet gateway to provide a secure internet access to my VPC, in this case I would like to know if enhanced routing can set to true for connecting via an s3 endpoint in the private subnet?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to use both a NAT Gateway and a VPC Endpoint. The Route Table for the private subnet would contain entries for them both. Because the routing rules for VPC Endpoint are more specific, traffic for S3 would go via the VPC Endpoint while other traffic would go via the NAT Gateway. So, the configuration you show in your Question should work just fine. Did you configure the VPC Endpoint with a "Full Access" policy?

Answer (score 0):

this can se setup by creating VPC endpoint service (producer) and creating an vpc endpoint (consumer) end. ref: AWS privatelinks