# S3 to Redshift traffic go over internet?

Tags: amazon-s3, https, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

We have data pipelines build to move data constantly from S3 to RedShift. I understand data is transferred over to redshift using copy command with HTTP/SSL protocol. My questions whether this traffic stays within VPC internal network or go over internet?

what if I'm transferring from S3 bucket to another S3 bucket in a different region, does it go over internet?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 has its own "back-end" connection to Amazon S3. The connection does not go via the VPC.

See: [Can not copy data from s3 to redshift cluster in a private subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558294/174777)

When transferring between Amazon S3 buckets in different regions, traffic will use Amazon-operated networks if they are available. (I'm not sure if data is transferred between two regions where there is no direct Amazon network connection.) However, the traffic is always encrypted.